# Infopath - Submit into Database Table code

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, vba, infopath

Is there any way to submit User created Fields into the InfoPath forms main database connection?

The reason I am asking this is because I am using code to copy values from a Secondary Data Connection into custom Fields which I have created in Infopath, however I can not do the same to copy the values in the main database connection, I have been looking for a workaround but no luck as of yet so I was wondering if there is any way to just submit my custom created fields into the Main connection?

I assume that this will have to be coded?

Thanks :)